# Much-Watch: How is this construction allowed?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, writing-style

I have received an email from *Crunchyroll* today, titled “*Discover Today’s **Much-Watch** Anime!*”. From the title, I immediately assumed that it’s about today’s “***must-watch***” anime series. The email actually rephrased “***much-watch***” to “***must-watch***”.

Whether or not phrasing “**much-watch**” is viewed as one of today’s wording trends, I was not sure if I understood the construction of “**much watch**”. It sounds catchy and I can understand its meaning (as a synonym for “**must watch**”), but I would like to ask you, the experts, about its correctness and soundness.

[image: see an email excerpt]

P.S. I contacted *Crunchyroll* about this email and **it turned out** that the email I received was a *phishing* email.
Now it’s no wonder that the email contained a noticeable **error** in grammar, spelling, or word usage.

Now I wish I have an answer to making a solid *compound adjective* in place of “***much-watch***”.

Comment: Still seems to be asking about a typo, or what would it mean if it was real?

Comment: I didn’t think it was a typo. It must be from one of the world’s trend-setters. I thought they might be setting a new standard of some sort by actually saying this and meaning something.

Comment: If a lot of people view the episode, it could be described as 'much-watched' anime, but it would be very hard to construct an idiomatically normal-sounding sentence that used 'much-watch' as a compound adjective.

Comment: Artistic license, or just a free-styling practice?

Comment: If everyone's watching, they wouldn't have to advertise. They use must-watch below. If you want to use it, go ahead. If you want to know if it's solid, no it's not.

Comment: Not as solid as something worthwhile to discuss its structure and usage. Understood.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Nothing is watched by *everyone*. It's common to use popularity as a proxy for quality in advertisements, to try to get others to watch. Think about all the advertisements touting "#1 bestseller".

Comment: But I'm on the typo side of the argument. Since anime is mostly a Japanese export, it's likely that the headline wasn't written by a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Russel Crowe uses the term on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/russellcrowe/status/1501387198662275075?lang=en):

> - For clarity: A “ much-watch “ movie is a must watch movie much watched…

Whether or not this licenses it I'd not like to say. One tends not to argue with Mr Crowe (and he does have expert knowledge in the field).

[Wildest cat from montana](https://forums.stevehoffman.tv/threads/what-films-would-you-say-are-a-regular-watch-for-you.1174286/) uses it as a noun / NP, in an obviously informal register (and a mixed metaphor):

> - 'The Ten Commandments' is a much watch every Easter but I can drop in on this movie any time, any scene and ride it out.

Perhaps a more convincing example comes from [Prostate Matters; possibly from the pen of Professor Chris Eden, Consultant Urological Surgeon
RETIRED from Royal Surrey County Hospital](https://prostatematters.co.uk/treatments-for-in-capsule-diagnoses-t1-t2/considering-robotic-prostatectomy-this-is-a-much-watch-video/):

> - Considering Robotic Prostatectomy? – this is a much watch video ...

[Virgin Media](https://www.virginmedia.com/virgin-tv-edit/tv/christmas-tv-guide-2019) use the term in their Christmas 2019 TV programme p/reviews:

> - Gogglebox: Best of 2019 ... The celebrity edition, which airs a few days earlier, is also a much-watch.

[Kirby Mcmullen](https://wfuogb.com/1802/sports/press-box-the-masters-is-a-much-watch-event/) writes in Old Gold & Black (the student-run newspaper of Wake Forest University)

> - The Masters is a much-watch event ...

And over 500 000 (raw figure) Google hits for "a much-watch" indicate that the expression is becoming established and acceptable.

Russel Crowe's definition shows the portmanteau nature of the coinage.

Certainly a [quantifier or adverb + infinitive] fusion (not a prototypical *blend*) is highly irregular ... if not unique. But if the two-word variant 'much watch' is chosen, and one rejects open compounds as some do, this is one more extragrammatical idiom to join say

- all of a sudden
- long time no see
- by and large.

Comment: I thought of a [pronoun + noun] fusion and that can be okay as an adjective. Same in “must-watch”, no?

Comment: No; that's [{modal} + {lexical verb infinitive}]. Like the compound adjective 'can-do'.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, and an answer. Glad to have this thread open to bring attention to this phrase. Living a transient life, I’m thrilled to witness a history in the making. Thank you.